# Subtracting UTC and non-UTC DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I assumed that when subtracting 2 datetimes the framework will check their timezone and make the appropriate conversions.

I tested it with this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime());
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() - DateTime.UtcNow);
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Output:

```
-00:00:00.0020002
-00:00:00.0020001
01:59:59.9989999
```

To my surprise, `DateTime.Now - DateTime.UtcNow` does not make the appropriate conversion automatically. At the same time, `DateTime.UtcNow` is the same as `DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime()`, so obviously there is some internal flag that indicates the time zone.

Is that correct, does that framework not perform the appropriate timezone conversion automatically, even if the information is already present? If so, is applying `ToUniversalTime()` safe for both UTC and non-UTC datetimes, i.e. an already UTC datetime will not be incorrectly corrected by `ToUniversalTime()`?

Comment: Different result in mono: http://ideone.com/AfFUpV

Comment: @zerkms I'm on VS2015, I don't know if it matters. Can you check on ideone with Visual Studio? I haven't personally used ideone much so I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: There is not time zone stored in the DateTime it just stores date and time. So it doesn't know in which time zone that DateTime is.

Comment: You are just stating a fact, readily visible from [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1057).  Use DateTimeOffset instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type `System.DateTime` does not hold time zone information, only a `.Kind` property that specifies whether it is Local or UTC. But before .NET 2.0, there was not even a `.Kind` property.

When you subtract (or do other arithmetic, like `==` or `>`, on) two `DateTime` values, their "kinds" are not considered at all. Only the numbers of ticks are considered. This gives compatibility with .NET 1.1 when [no kinds existed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx).

The functionality you ask for (and expect) is in the newer and richer [type `System.DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx). In particular, if you do the subtraction `DateTimeOffset.Now - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` you get the result you want. The `DateTimeOffset` structure does not have a local/UTC flag; instead, it holds the entire time zone, such as +02:00 in your area.

Comment: Yes, coming from Qt, QDateTime holds a UTC time plus a timezone offset.   I expected DateTime to use it, and was a little confused when Hans Passant mentioned DateTimeOffset, because it sounded like a TimeSpan rather than what DateTime should have been.

Comment: Not much of a proper explanation, IMHO. There isn't much in the .NET Framework that remains (or ever remained) beholden to .NET 1.0/1.1 backwards compatibility, .NET 2.0 is the compatibility strived for.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi The type `DateTimeOffset` that I mentioned was introduced in .NET 2.0. When I described _why_ the functionality of `DateTime` was chosen the way it was, when .NET 2.0 was introduced and `DateTime` acquired a `Kind` property, I was guessing a bit. However, when I described _how_ `DateTime` actually works, since .NET 2.0, I was correct.

Answer (score 1):

The framework does nothing with the date if it is already UTC:

```
 internal static DateTime ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfoOptions flags)
{
    if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
    {
        return dateTime;
    }
    CachedData cachedData = s_cachedData;
    return ConvertTime(dateTime, cachedData.Local, cachedData.Utc, flags, cachedData);
}
```

Comment: Though you have to be careful about `DateTimeKind.Unknown` (which can often come from querying a DB). In that case if you call `ToUniversalTime` it will assume local and convert to UTC, and if you call `ToLocalTime`it will assume UTC and convert to local.

Comment: @ChrisChilvers That is an important observation.

Comment: The question is focused on the case where the `ToUniversalTime()` is ___not___ used. An explanation of how `ConvertTimeToUtc` works is not helpful in answering the case the question asked for. The method is not called in that case. If you want to post source code, post the code for `public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen , one of the questions was is it safe to apply ToUniversalDateTime to an UTC date time.

Comment: You are right, I focused too much on one aspect of the question (the one in the subject).